# Can we have cassandra only nodes and solr enabled nodes in same datacenter?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I just started with solr and would like your suggestion in below scenario. We have 2 data centers with 3 nodes in each data center(both in different aws regions for location advantage). We have a requirement for which they asked me if we can have 2 solr nodes in each data center. so it will be 2 solr nodes and 1 cassandra only node in each data center. I want to understand if its fine to have this kind of setup and I am little confused whether solr nodes will have data on it along with the indexes? does all 6 nodes share data and 4 solr nodes will have indexes on it along with data?  Kindly provide some information on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is **no**, this will not work. **If you turn on DSE Search on one node in a DC you need to turn it on for all the nodes in the DC.**

#### But why??

DSE Search builds lucene indexes on the data that is stored local to a node. Say you have a 3 node DC with RF1 (the node only has 1/3rd of the data) and you only turn on search on one of the nodes. 1/3 of your search queries will fail.

#### So I should just turn search on everywhere?

If you have a relatively small workloads with loose SLA's (both c* and search) and/or if you are over provisioned, you may be fine turning on Search on your main Cassandra nodes. However, in many cases with heavy c* workloads and tight SLA's, Search queries will negatively affect cassandra performance (because they are contending against the same hardware).

#### I need search nodes in both Physical DC's

If you want search enabled only in two out of your three nodes in a physical DC, the only way to do this is to actually split up your physical DC into two logical DC's. In your case you would have:

US - Cassandra

US - Search

Singapore - Cassandra

Singapore - Search

This gives you geographic locality for your search and c* queries and also provides [workload isolation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployWkLdSep.html) between your c* and search workloads since they contend against different OS Subsystems.

Comment: This is why it is so important to have DataStax folks out here on SO.  Every now and then we (engineers) get asked questions about using Cass/DSE in goofy ways, and the mere seconds it took you to answer this pales in comparison to the time that we spend Googling things like this. +1

Comment: @phact Many thanks for the fast response. We have 2 aws regions/DC, one in us and another in singapore for client location benefit. They wanted to have solr enabled for both regions(2 in 3 nodes in each dc). And we are having replication factor of 3 in each dc. In your example I guess its 2/3 of queries fail and 1/3 will succeed. And if we have RF=3 and have solr enabled only on 2 nodes in each dc then 2/3 queires will succeed and 1/3 will fail. P:lease correct me if i am wrong and it would be great help if you can suggest best case (have solr enabled on all 3+3 nodes?) ManyThanks!!